# How do I enroll to Google Play App Signing from a Visual Studio (Xamarin) generated keystore?

Tags: visual-studio, keystore, google-play-console

I have a Xamarin application which I have published to the Google Play store in the `.apk` format using a `Foo.keystore` (generated by Visual Studio) and `Foo` alias. With the new Google policies I will be soon required to use the `.aab` format, which in itself is not an issue. When uploading my `.aab` the Google PLay Console, I am required to opt-in to "Play App Signing" and essentially asked to upload my existing private key and also a new "upload" key.

**How do I upload the private key from my `Foo.keystore` to "Opt in to Play App Signing"?**

I'd also like to know how to create a new upload key? I understand this is optional and Google could generate one for me, but I'd like to do it the "properway".

In the "opt-in" dialogue I am presented with three options:

- Export and upload a key from Android Studio
- Export and upload a key from Java keystore
- Export and upload a key (not using Java Keystore)

I have attempted the first option (Android Studio) and ran the following command to export the key:
`C:\Program Files\Android\jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25\jre\bin>keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore E:\Temp\Foo.keystore -destkeystore E:\Temp\Foo.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12`

However I got the error message: "*The private key was not properly encrypted or is not a type of key we support.*" when uploading the file in the opt-in dialogue.

Note:  The other options required me to run some Java app and I want to avoid installing / learning Java just to execute a tool and I'm really not sure how to proceed. I have searched Stack Overflow and other resources and did not find any clear info on how to proceed.

Any adivices and pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: I have solved part of the question. I was able to extract the key while using modified instructions from option "Export and upload a key from Java keystore. It seems like the .keystore file is indeed a Java Keystore. -- I'm still researching the second part of the question concerning the upload key. -- I will create an answer if I find the complete solution.

Comment: I'm stuck with this. How did you manage to get the VS key to upload to the Google Console?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It has been some time since this question was posted, looks like there are still users struggling to find the right way.

In the Visual Studio, after creating an Archive, you choose Distribute->Ad hoc, and then you generate a new Keystore containing a certificate. It will be saved in C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\Keystore\KEYSTORENAME.

Visual Studio generates a keystore with the extension .keystore, however, it is the same format as Java keystore (.jks).

To upload the PEM certificate to Google developer console, you need to extract it from the keystore generated by the Visual Studio, using the utility keytool.

To get keytool, you need to download a Java JDK. Then, keytool will be in the bin folder.

You may consider to run the keytool within the Visual Studio Tools->Android->Android ADB command prompt.

Use keytool to extract the PEM certificate from the keystore:

keytool -export -rfc -keystore **path-and-name-of-your-keystore** -alias **upload** -file **upload_certificate.pem**

(All **bold text** replace with your values.)

Please, keep in mind that all arguments, above all paths, which contain space, must be enclosed into **" "**. Otherwise they will be considered as multiple separate arguments: **"**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin\keytool.exe**"** .

In the Google developer console, under Setup->App Integrity->App signing, under Upload key certificate, you click on Request upload key reset.

Then, on the modal screen, you will be allowed to upload the new PEM certificate to Google developer console.

This should work until Google does not change its way of handling upload certificates again...